# Use two or more relational operators in one sentence in python

Tags: python, relational

How do two or more relational operators in a single sentence work? For example:

```
5 < 5 <= 3 > 10
```

Comment: Usually, you'd see something like `0 < x < 10`, which does pretty much what you'd expect it to do from mathematics. People generally won't chain `<` and `>` in the same expression.

Answer (score 2):

https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#comparisons

It's evaluated in order, so your expression expands to

```
5 < 5 and 5 <= 3 and 3 > 10
```

which evaluates to `False`

Answer (score 2):

Python supports double-ended comparisons.  For example,

```
3 < x <= 7
```

is a check for `3 < x` and `x <= 7` (with `x` being evaluated just once).

By extension,

```
5 < 5 <= 3 > 10
```

means `(5 < 5)` and `(5 <= 3)` and `(3 > 10)`, all of which are `False`, so the whole expression evaluates to `False`.